# Jquery sliding div disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a jquery site and I have a slide in and out div that I'm using to show share buttons.  I'm using the same code on multiple pages.  On my first page it works great with no problems but every other page the div will slide out but slide right back in.  It doesn't stop.  Very confused.

Here I have a fiddle and in the fiddle it works great!  But when I use the same code on other pages it's not working correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/4hUzH/

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.toggleNotes').click(function() {        
$nextArticle = $(this).next('.article');        
$nextArticle.is(':visible') ? $nextArticle.slideUp() : $nextArticle.slideDown();         
return false;    
});
});
</script>

<style>
.article {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<a href="#" class="toggleNotes">Click here</a>

<div class="article">
    This is where the buttons show up.
</div>
```

Can anyone explain why it slides out and right back in?

Comment: well it's not really helpful to show us a code that is already working. Could you expand on how this code is shared between pages? it is found in each page? is it in a js file and you're including on each page? Is it possible to view the pages?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in my top.php I was also calling the same function.  So it was calling the instance twice.  It only needs to be called once.  Silly mistake.